# Views: does k mean one thousand?

Tags: support, user-interface, views

Stupid question filter:

Does this mean that the question has been viewed *two thousand times*?

[image]

I ask because I've seen queries that would never get that many hits listed as having absurdly high numbers of views, and it occurs to me that I might be interpreting the views number, um, totally  wrong.

Comment: `I've seen queries that would never get that many hits listed as having absurdly high` - some examples?

Comment: Well, perhaps not. Now that I'm embarrassed and looking more carefully, I'm realizing these entries with 151kviews are two years old and could easily have garnered that many hits.

Comment: The particular question is 10 months old - however there have been newer questions which have got more views thanks to auto tweets & questions being featured on http://stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm just stupidly unobservant sometimes. *blush*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the k does stand for thousands of views.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it means 2,000 views. If you mouseover it, the hovertext will tell you just how many views exactly.  Also, if you click through to the question, the right sidebar will tell you the exact number of views.

Comment: Hovertext. Thanks. Had literally never noticed that.